# Windows authentication with Ldap in Python

Tags: python, authentication, flask, ldap, window

I am using python flask to develop web services. I want to make web service secure.
 Need to consume those from Ajax.

I have tried Okta integration but as it is depends on redirect I couldn't achieve the integration.
I am thinking to go for windows authentication with our org ldap directory.

Getting windows username and password from windows logged in user and authenticating with ldap.

Could anyone please help me how to achieve it or please post the suggestions for better solution.

Comment: You can use the [python-ldap](https://github.com/python-ldap/python-ldap) library

Comment: or [ldap3](https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3) library.

Comment: But I don't have any view page to enter username and password. I am trying to get those form windows logged in. Is it possible to get username and password from client window logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get the username and password from the Windows client -- being able to grab the logon user's password from a remote web site would be an enormous security nightmare.

Assuming *not* simply asking the user to supply credentials is a non-negotiable design parameter, you need something that can use the logged on user's token ('I trust this token and it says you are this user ID') instead of trying to validate the user/password directly. [Kerberos-based authentication](https://flask-kerberos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if the Windows boxes are logging into an Active Directory & your app is on the same network. Otherwise you'd need some sort of SSO (I frequently use ADFS, if that's set up for the organisation, via [MS Graph](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/python-sample-auth)) -- ***what*** would depend on the specifics of the directories available.

Comment: Hey thanks Lisa for your valuable response. I have done LDAP authentication by some service account. Trying to get windows user name by request.environ.get('REMOTE_USER') and querying ldap for details. Used ajax to call the service. But I am getting 401  Unauthorized and No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Used apache wsgi with flask services.

Comment: Any comments please